# How to deduct from only one row?

Tags: sql-server

Let say I have 3 rows that have the same customer id `Invoice_CustomerName`. However, I only want to deduct the no. of appointment `Invoice_TotalAppointment` which is only from the first row. My query below will deduct 1 appointment for every row that has the same customer id.

```
UPDATE InvoiceNew SET Invoice_TotalAppointment = Invoice_TotalAppointment - 1
                    WHERE Invoice_CustomerName = @Appointment_ContactID
```

How can I deduct only for the first row?

Comment: An example to help you select only one row: SELECT TOP 1 MyTable1.Date
FROM MyTable1 
INNER JOIN MyTable2 
  ON MyTable1.Id = MyTable2.Id
WHERE Name = 'John' 
ORDER BY MyTable1.Date DESC

Comment: in summary: You can use TOP and order by to retrieve only one row you need. then update it

Comment: DO you have any Unique ID column in this table? share complete table structure, You can select ID first based on @Appointment_ContactID and then update the table based on selected ID.

Comment: well the first thing you have to decide is how you define the "first" row? What makes that row unique, or what gives it the "first" position in that list of 3? Note that SQL tables have no built-in ordering (the order you inserted the records is not considered when selecting or updating them)...so you need to have another field which will help you identify which one is "first", and then reference that field appropriately in your WHERE clause

Comment: @MukeshArora, each of the table have the PK. Invoice_ID, Appointment_ID and Contact_ID. Both table, Appointment and InvoiceNew only have the Contact_ID.

Comment: @ADyson The flow is like this: After creating the appointment, it will deduct the remaining no. of appointment. When the remaining no.of appointment is 0, it will deduct the remaining no. of appointment from the next row. I have no idea how to do the query

Comment: @testtest ok, but none of that answers the points I made in my comment. You haven't explained how you are going to identify the "first" or "next" row. How do you define the order of the rows? Since we don't know what other data you hold, we can't answer that for you, we can only make generic suggestions, as I've already done. I'm guessing that maybe since you have no idea how to approach it, that might mean that you haven't actually got any data which would enable you to make that definition?

Comment: @testtest Mind you, having said that, it seems like an odd requirement anyway. If you're storing an invoice, which stores the number of appointments someone is entitled to based on that appointment, then surely you want to preserve that information, so that you have proof of their original entitlement? Subtracting values from that formal record sounds unwise to me, unless you have a separate record of the original data somewhere else in your tables....

Comment: @testtest .... I assume that you must also have an Appointments table where you record what appointments each customer has actually booked and attended? And maybe you even link each appointment to the invoice ID where it was billed? If so, then if you want to know how many appointments a customer has remaining, you can just fetch the sum of the totalappointment field, minus the number of appointments for that customer which exist in the appointments field (and you can restrict that by a specific invoice ID if needed).

Comment: @ADyson, that's why I'm making this question because I have no idea how to deduct only from the first row which means I also have no idea about identifying the first and next row

Comment: @testtest So basically you don't have to **store** that information, you can just **calculate** it whenever you need to know it. That's a common technique in relational databases - if there's some information which can be calculated based on looking at other pieces of data, then as a general rule you don't ever store that information, because it's redundant to do so - you can just run a query to calculate the current value of it whenever it's needed. (N.B. The main reason you might break that rule is to improve performance, if the calculation is very slow.)

Comment: "I also have no idea about identifying the first and next row"...well neither do any of us, because we have no idea about your business rules. You probably need some sort of field like the date the row was added, which would enable you to put them in the right order. It's up to **you** to decide what attribute it is which defines that order. But read my last few comments before you carry on - I actually think you need to consider whether you really want to do this task at all.

Comment: @ADyson, the Invoice have two table, one is Invoice and the other one is InvoiceDetail. The InvoiceDetail have the actual value of the no. of appointment. InvoiceDetail hold the PK of Invoice. So meaning the totalappointment field in Invoice is just same as totalappointment field in InvoiceDetail

Comment: @ADyson The requirement is I need to do auto deduct when an appointment has been made, so that the customer will know how many no. of appointment left.

Comment: "The requirement is I need to do auto deduct when an appointment has been made, so that the customer will know how many no. of appointment left" ...that's what I'm saying...you don't need to auto-deduct in order to know that. If you keep a record of the appointments booked, you can just subtract that from the original total in order to know how many are left, rather than destroying the original record of how many the customer was first entitled to (which might easily be something you or they later want to query).

Comment: "the totalappointment field in Invoice is just same as totalappointment field in InvoiceDetail" ...unless you haven't described it very well, this sounds like a strange and probably unnecessary duplication of data. You should never be storing the same data twice in a relational database. Also what is the relationship between the Invoice and InvoiceDetail tables exactly? if it's a 1-to-1 relationship then why have you even got 2 tables?

Comment: @ADyson, Invoice hold the general data such as customer name, address, email, phone number and etc. InvoiceDetail hold the data of which package and how many package did the customer purchase. Let say the customer purchase 2 Package A (have 4 appointment) and 1 Package B (have 12 appointment). So in table InvoiceDetail will have 2 row, one is Package A, another one is Package B, both row holding the PK of Invoice. The table Invoice holding the total of the appointment ((2*4) + (1*12))

Comment: Right that makes sense then. But... "The table Invoice holding the total of the appointment ((2*4) + (1*12))" ...again this is redundant data, because it can be calculated on-demand by looking at the contents of the InvoiceDetail table. You should avoid storing redundant data like this unless it's absolutely necessary to avoid performance problems. Just calculate it in a query whenever you want to know it. That way you don't then have the extra step of keeping it up to date when the source information changes.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve my question :)

```
UPDATE InvoiceNew SET Invoice_TotalAppointment = Invoice_TotalAppointment - 1
           WHERE Invoice_ID = (SELECT MIN(Invoice_ID) FROM InvoiceNew 
                      WHERE Invoice_CustomerName = @Appointment_ContactID 
                      AND (IsDelete = 0 OR IsDelete = NULL)
                      AND (Invoice_TotalAppointment != 0))
```